# How do I correctly insert a curly bracket in a table cell

Tags: tables, brackets

So I made a table in which I would like to have a curly bracket, containing three formulas in one cell. I managed to make one that look right in the pdf, tho I still get an error message.

[image]

So this is what I want, and also what I get when I export to pfd. But there are a few errors that come up which I don't know how to fix.

```
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l l}
            \hline
            Polaire vergelijking & Cartesiaans equivalent\\
            \hline
            $r \cos\theta = 2$ & $x=2$\\
            $r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta = 4$ & $xy=4$\\
            $r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta=1$ & $x^2-y^2=1$\\
            $r=1+2r\cos\theta$ & \left\{ \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}} $y^2-3x^2-4x-1=0$\\  $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1+2x$\\ $x^2+y^2=(1+2x)^2$ \end{tabular} \right.\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: `\left\{` needs math mode so you need `$` as in your other math mode cells

Comment: Do you mean around the entire \left\{ ? Because when I do that the bracket becomes a smaller one. So I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: @robbestephan I think @David Carlisle `$\left\{` .......... `\right.$` meant this.

Comment: Ok, makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may liked:

[image]

Instead nested `tabular` is used `cases` environment defined in the `amsmath` package. For more vertical space is added `makecell` package to preamble and in code for table used its macro `\makegapedcells`. Instead tabular is used `array` and it is enclosed in math environment. By this you not need to write `$` before and after each equations in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % <---
\usepackage{makecell} % <---

\begin{document}
\[    
\setcellgapes{3pt} % <---
\makegapedcells    % <---
    \begin{array}{l l}
        \hline
    $Polaire vergelijking$ & $Cartesiaans equivalent$   \\
        \hline
r \cos\theta = 2                    & x=2           \\
r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta = 4      & xy=4          \\
r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta=1   & x^2-y^2=1     \\
r=1+2r\cos\theta                    & \begin{cases} 
                            y^2-3x^2-4x-1=0         \\  
                            \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1+2x     \\ 
                            x^2+y^2=(1+2x)^2    
                                      \end{cases}   \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Comment: If answer solve your problem, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).